# How is Android Firebase messaging SDK secure against Intent spoofing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a simple project using Firebase Messaging, using the following dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
```

I have built the app and checked its *merged* AndroidManifest.xml file. The only exported component by Firebase Messaging SDK is the following receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I couldn't find the definition of the permission `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND`, even though I have decoded AndroidManifest.xml of Google Play Services APK and found nothing there. Apart from its definition whatever it is, it cannot prevent a malicious app to `use-permission` it and broadcast forged Intents. Also because of Intents being delivered by `system_server`, the receiver cannot check the identity of the sender.

How does Firebase Messageing SDK counterattack this threat?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what type of attack you're asking about. Can you maybe describe what the malicious user would do, and what secure data would be exposed that way?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen A malicious app can use the permission `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` and send intents with action `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` to a victim app. This way the victim thinks the Intent has received from the authorized source. I don't know FCM messages are delivered using this `receiver` or not, but if so, the malicious app can sent a forged FCM message to a target app.

Comment: To send a message to the device through FCM you need the ID token of that device, and you need the FCM Server Key. How would the malicious user get both of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A malicious app installed from the Play Store cannot use any permission that starts with "com.google.android".  Those are reserved for system privileged apps.

The Play services "backend" app, which is installed on every device that has the Play store, actually handles incoming FCM messages directly.  It is a privileged app, and is the only one that will use those permissions to send data to your app.

If you manage to root your device and install a malicious app with system privileges, then you might have a problem.  But that's the risk you take when you bypass the security measures built into the device.

Comment: So, the `protectionLevel` for this permission should be `signature|privileged`. Okay, that's fine. Could you please tell me how are messages sent from the "backend" app to my app? through a `receiver`? or something else?

Comment: Through the very same receiver that gets merged into the manifest that you showed above.

Comment: AFAIK the method `onMessageReceived` is required to return at most in 9 seconds otherwise the "gone async" BroadcastReceiver is "finished". Unfortunately I couldn't find a reason for binding to a service from the receiver and off load the tasks to it to handle. Why not users extend that `receiver` and do the message-arrive tasks there? What's the advantage of running a limited service (i.e. `FirebaseMessagingService`)  for handling the tasks?

Comment: It sounds like you have a whole new question that's different than your original one.  Please post it separately.