# ANR on FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting the following error in my play console without any stack trace (on android 7 and 10).

```
Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.mycompany.myapp cmp=com.mycompany.myapp/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }
```

Firebase version used,

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.6'
```

I don't know which part of my code exactly causing this error, I'm posting the code that is responsible for uploading the `FCM token` to my server.

MyFirebaseMessagingService,

```
 @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
       new TokenUploader().setFcmToken();//send to server
    }
```

TokenUploader class

```
    //this function is called from MyFirebaseMessagingService and MainActivity
    public void setFcmToken() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) new Thread(() -> pushFcmToken(task.getResult())).start();
            else if (task.getException() != null)
                new Thread(() -> pushFcmToken(task.getException().getMessage())).start();
        });
    }


    //push token to server
    private void pushFcmToken(String token) {
        if (account == null) return;
        try {
            JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
            params.put("email", account.getEmail());
            params.put("password", getPassword());
            params.put("key", getApiKey());
            params.put("fcm_token", token);
            JSONObject obj = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {//try 4 times
                obj = sendRequestToApi("POST", params, "/fcm_route");
                if (obj != null && obj.has("fcmId")) break;//successfully uploaded
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
           
        }
    }
```

I strongly believe that I'm doing something wrong here, because a good number of devices have failed to upload their token to my server. How can I prevent the above error and get a 100% success rate in uploading the token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These ANRs for `act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` are very common in Android apps which are sending a lot of push notifications.

Most of them are caused by long application startup and processing push notifications on the main thread.
Nickolay Chameyev from the Bumble Tech described it well in article: [How we achieved a 6x reduction of ANRs - Part 2: Fixing ANRs](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/how-we-achieved-a-6x-reduction-of-anrs-part-2-fixing-anrs-24fedf9a973f).

Comment: My app indeed has a very long startup time. I don’t know what is the exact reason for it. In my app's ```onCreate```, I have a ```realm ```database, ```Admob```, and some ```MutableLiveData``` initializations. Tried to run the app without these initializations, and tried with an ```empty launcher activity``` but the startup time is still 4-5 seconds. I don’t know how to fix it?

Comment: Every app is different and reasons of long startup are many. In this article you can also find some tips how to improve it. If there is nothing suspicious in Application class then you can check manifest for some initializers/content providers. In case when you use hilt you can check scopes of dependencies which you create. We should rather avoid Singleton scope if we want to improve startup time

Comment: I couldn’t find anything suspicious in my Manifest. Is there any way to find what caused the long startup time using android studio built-in tools?

Comment: ```Application.onCreate``` is called 3 seconds after the splash screen is started.

Comment: You can use CPU profiler to find bottlenecks: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

Comment: I think it's important to note if you were using a splash screen and kept it (manually)for longer than 2 sec it is considered ANR.

Answer (score 1):

You may use it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
```

You also update your all firebase service and update Plugin `“com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3”`

You may check this for more clear. [Link](https://lightrun.com/answers/firebase-firebase-android-sdk-not-allowed-to-start-service-intent--actcomgoogleandroidc2dmintentregister-pkgcomgoogleand)

Comment: could you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: 1. First you add this permission in your manifest.
2. Add google play service. 
3. Add all firebase service with update.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of google play services and firebase. Could you please explain why I have to add these Permissions? I couldn’t find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: Some android version notifications did not work properly. That time you used this system for more accuracy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58527280/1800333

Answer (score 1):

Your entire logic to upload the FCM token appears to be too complex.

1. In your service, when you already have received the new FCM token, can't you just pass it to setFcmToken() function directly?
2. Why threads? It would be better if you use work manager instead.

Plus, make sure you aren't doing anything extra in your FirebaseInstanceID service and in your TokenUploader class. This might also help: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3052

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to implement the work manager. Could you please explain why the thread is a bad idea? In my ```FirebaseMessagingService``` I have ```threads``` for writing database entries and showing notifications(which has network call).

Comment: Mostly all Firebase*Services have a time threshold for completing the callback. The documentation clearly mentioned that you should use a Job dispatcher (WorkManager) for all the long-running operations. The Firebase*Services callbacks are meant only for data collections, nothing less nothing more.

Comment: This is a chat application. When ```FirebaseMessagingService``` receives a message, it runs a thread that saves the message to a realm database and fetches the sender's profile picture from API (Using glide, so mostly it’s going to be a disk cache read), and displays it in the notification. So, shall I replace this thread with a work manager? Will the work manager be able to run immediately?

Comment: It should be, depending on what constraints you put. Another thing you can do is trigger a notification immediately, and fork off a job to save the message into realm DB using work manager.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest file. also no need to call methods **setFcmToken function** you can directly write pushFcmToken in onNewToken method.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="{applicationId}.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

use of this permission is to that This app has permission to register and receive data message.

Comment: Why they didn't mention this in the documentation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58527280/1800333

Comment: yeah that's why we have used the protectionLevel for security reason. permission should be signature|privileged

Comment: Okay, I'm still confused. Why firebase documentation doesn’t mention anything about these permissions? Also, I guess the ANR is caused by the long network operation I'm doing in the ```MyFirebaseMessagingService``` as newer versions of android have limitations on background processing. Do I still need these permissions?

Comment: you can check this doc to know info about this permission
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleCloudMessaging/article.html