# com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1080010 pkg=com.example.pkg cmp=com.example.pkg/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver, anr

Hello Friends i Recive tons of ANR'S on Play Console
ANR is Generated when App is Close and FCM is Received
any one can please help me thanks in Advance
when=-5s587ms what=113 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1080010 pkg=com.example.pkg cmp=com.example.pkg /com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) } packageName=com.example.pkg  resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null} }

I tried to update and degrade Firebase sdk but not work.
i tried below things but not works..

`

```
<receiver android:exported="true"
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:directBootAware="true" android:exported="false"
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/notification_channel_id"/>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73126231/20447561) about ANRs. The answer provides some tips on how to resolve or lessen the ANRs in your app.